# Wordpress custom ul class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need help for my custom Wordpress Layout.
It should look like this (HTML):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
             <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In Wordpress:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2">Test/Site</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Code:

```
<?php 
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse' ) ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check here and tell me if it helps: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 1):

I think 
This

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse' ) ); ?>
```

Should be:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse', ''menu_class'=>'nav navbar' ) ); ?`>

May be this can help:

```
$args = array(
 'theme_location' => 'primary'
  'items_wrap'     => '<ul class="nav nav-menu">%3$s</ul>',
  'walker'         => '',
)
```

not tested it though

Comment: Try removing theme location index if it is not of use

Comment: This should work for sure. Are you sure you are checking the correct menu? Clear your cache and then check may be page is cached?